# Firebase Auth using phone number and password

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am developing Android app using Firebase. Because of that, I want to use Firebase Auth. I have following requirements:

- Register/Log in using Facebook
- Register/Log in using Email/Password
- Register/Log in using **Phone Number/Password**

The first two are OK, I followed basic [tutorials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). However, **Phone Number / Password** is the problem here. Firebase supports only Phone Number/SMS Token for this (its called Phone Auth), but there is no mention about my case. I do not want to hack Firebase and use its realtime database instead of Auth 'database'. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: "hack Firebase"?

Comment: I mean to search for some workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase  phone authentication is using OTP(one time password). This way there is no hassle for the user to remember the password. Once authenticated, you will be registered. The sms code acts as a password. But that is for one time. Usually , users prefer such behaviour in which you dont have to remember the passwords. If you are still looking for the way you want, see this link and create a custom authentication method. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Answer (score 10):

**Use Fake Email:**

Well, Firebase doesn't support sign in with mobile number and password but it supports email and password. So you can create a fake email with your mobile number.

Ie: `78******69@yourdomain.com`

Also, you can create a complete Authentication system using it.

**Registration:**

- Input user mobile and password and proceed to the next page.
- Now use Firebase Phone Auth (OTP) to createUser. If process success, link fake email, password credentials in background.

  `AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);`
  `auth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential);`

**Login:**

- Input mobile and password to login. Convert the mobile in fake email and then `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`.

**Forget Password:**

- Redirect the user to a new Page and user Phone Auth to verify the user. If successful, input a new password and change the password of the Email Auth.

Comment: this works for only phone/password. problem is, what if we need to support of both email/password and phone/password, In that case how do you link the valid email address with the single user

Comment: Check the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) 
 `mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)`

Comment: Use Firebase Admin SDK

Comment: In the case where the user forgot their password, i am not able to update the users password because i do not have a currentUser signed in. The user entered their mobile number and it was verified now the user needs to enter password to login, the user forgot their password and is navigated to enter a new password. How do i go about and update the users password?

Answer (score 7):

If you have both email and phone of your user and you can use Admin SDK, then perhaps you could exchange users phone number to his email and login with email and password in the background.

Something like this (node.js)

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    .then(user => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password);
    });
```

Comment: @Alvis so it does both, OTP verification and password verification, right?

Comment: @lazzy_ms this enables to log in user using his phone and password. The same password he has for his email. It does not prevent using OTP. So I guess the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: When login also ask for otp?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem - 
I combined firebase auth(email + password) with (phone+otp) to get phone+password auth -

https://medium.com/@shivampesitbng/firebase-phone-password-auth-in-vue-b94f15b8fb3d

Comment: This is creating an email with phone number embedded in it - `+91xxxx@domain.com`. An interesting hack.

Comment: Interesting but the problem is you wont be able to link two firebase accounts together if in future user decided to add his email in his account for login. In this case one user will have two firebase unique IDs.