# Setting password after phone authentication via Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I need a help regarding the code for setting password after Phone Number Authentication using firebase such that after first time verification of phone number user can directly log in using phone number and password

Comment: See this answer for a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351512/firebase-auth-using-phone-number-and-password?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Not clear to me..please elaborate and expalin

Comment: I'm not sure I can add anything to the question and responses that would tell you more?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a password after phone authentication but phone+password authentication is not supported with Firebase Auth. You can link an email/password provider to the account but the user would be able to sign in with phone OR email+password and not phone+password.