# How to login an existing firebase user without an otp code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I am using Firebase Phone Authentication for signing up my new users. An OTP is sent to their mobile and if they are verified their data are stored in my MYSQL table. Here is the table:

```
id | user_id | phone_number | isAuthenticated
=============================================
1  |   10    | ************ |  0
2  |   11    | ************ |  1
3  |   12    | ************ |  1
4  |   13    | ************ |  0
```

When a user's phone number is verified, the 'isAuthenticated' is set to 1. My question is when a user is trying to re-login into his/her account, can I just do some `signInWithCredential(phonenumber)` and login the user without having to send an otp again? Is there a way to do this in Firebase? Or is there a way to sign in the user using the User UID in the Firebase user table? Hope you will answer. Regards.

Comment: I believe logins not work in that way. Firebase sends login OTP to verify if the mobile number matches their records and and notifies that the user is a trusted registered user of the app using auth. I'm confused on why you want not to send OTP to make login. What possible things you are trying to do with that feature.

Comment: No I just want to verify the user is not a bot on signing up, thus sending an otp to verify for the first time. The second time when the user is trying to login, just check if the user is authenticated from my sql table and login the user without an otp code. This is what I am trying to achieve. Thank You.

Comment: As per this user answer you have to use the firebase custom authentication to get what the feature what you are looking for. Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/46352032/16108645

Comment: But I can give a hack on how to achieve such behaviour you are looking for. First seperate login and register and in login when you receive the phone number from input check it whether the user number is in your database and if found allow user to login else ask him to register. While registering get the authentication token from phone Auth and save it and later pass this to your custom auth method and you are done.

Comment: Thank You! Wil look onto your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After Firebase verify that the mobile number matches,
In your apps, you can get the user's basic profile information from the **`FirebaseUser`** object. So you don't need to use again `signInWithCredential` method. Because as long as the user has not cleaned app datas or uninstalled it, Sign in credentials will still be available through **`FirebaseUser`**.
see See [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users).

Comment: Yes I understand that but when the user logs out, the firebase user also gets logged out as well. And I need to get the firebaseuser during the re-login even if the users has cleared cache or the data. Hope I made you clear.