# I want to login with mobile number and password

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5vpA.png)i have registered a user in firebase which has its details saved in registered Users table and now i want that user to login through otp verified number and password.

Comment: Can you show what you tried already? Without that, it is unlikely we're going to do a better job than https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Comment: Sir i dont have idea all the links and video which saw shows how to login with email and password non of them was how to login with mobile number and password.

Comment: Ah, got it. There's no built-in provider for Firebase that allows the user to sign in with phone number and password. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351512/firebase-auth-using-phone-number-and-password and more from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+phone+number+and+password. Also check out https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/android/mfa. Google Cloud's Identity Platform is a paid upgrade of Firebase that adds features like multi-factor authentication, which may be what you're looking for.